# differently styling nested blockquotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site with some text features, but it does mean that a multitude of nested `blockquote`s is a possibility. Now I am wondering if it is possible to have the styling for nested blockquotes be different from eachother!

```
blockquote{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

so that is a simple version of a blockquote styling. My question would be this:

What can I do to make it such that every other blockquote within a blockquote has a black background instead!

Anything like that! Maybe only the 4th nested blockquote has a white border.

Just being able to manipulate nested blockquotes would be very useful to me!

[Here is a jsfiddle with a couple nested blockquotes](http://jsfiddle.net/GqUwW/)

Thanks!

P.S. I am open to using any of the 4 tagged languages, no php please.

**EDIT NOTE:**

I cannot actually give ids to the `blockquote`s because it is based through users. If you do use IDs or Classes, it must be added to the specific blockquotes through jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses jquery to apply a specific css class to every even `blockquote`:

```
$('blockquote').each(function(index, element){
     if(index % 2 == 0) { $(element).addClass('even'); }
 });
```

You can extend upon this to customize a specific element (let's say the 4th blockquote) by checking for `index == 3`

This should save you the hassle of writing and maintaining extra CSS or setting static, arbitrary IDs on your html elements. Here's a JS fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/ncnre/7/

Comment: at first glance it seems about right, but does anyone have idea how to make even LEVELS of nested blockquotes special and not something like this http://jsfiddle.net/z3cbn6La/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's tougher to target specific blockquotes in this case if they are just nested and have no IDs or classes. But take a look at this fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4zyR/. Is this what you are looking for?

I would recommend adding IDs to the blockquote elements if possible.

Updated CSS:

```
    blockquote{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}

blockquote blockquote{
    background-color: white;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}

blockquote blockquote blockquote{
    background-color: red;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

Or with JQuery as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4zyR/1/. Pull all the blockquotes, then style every other.

Comment: this is great, so +1, but it doesn't help me out with things such as every other blockquote and such, so once patterns can be determined, then I can accept the answer

Comment: Ok, take a gander now: http://jsfiddle.net/m4zyR/1/, using JQuery to update every other blockquote

Comment: add that to your answer and I'll approve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could follow a pattern like this, though it's a bit messy:

```
blockquote{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}

blockquote blockquote {background: red;}

blockquote blockquote blockquote {background: green;}

blockquote blockquote blockquote blockquote {background: blue;}
```

Comment: this is great, so +1, but it doesn't help me out with things such as every other blockquote and such, so once patterns can be determined, then I can accept the answer

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't help me out with things such as every other blockquote". Could you clarify?

Comment: for example, how would i be able to do this if i wanted every other nested blockquote to be black

Comment: Obviously you could do it manually, by changing red and blue above to black. This would be easy with CSS3 selectors if the blockquotes were siblings, but I'm not not sure that works with nested elements.

Comment: well for all I know, there could be 25 nested blockquotes, although unlikely, so I can't really do it manually...and yeah I don't think that would work

Comment: As you say, it's unlikely to have so many nested blockquotes, so you can just keep repeating the pattern above to a reasonable limit.

Comment: yes, but that's not the point. This site creates a blockquote whenever another user shares something from another. If this results in a thread-like situation, it could have a large amount. Plus being able to do interesting patterns would be nice. Maybe Jquery? But I can't think of how...

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GqUwW/3/

HTML:

```
<blockquote id="b1">Blockquote
    <blockquote id="b2">Blockquote
        <blockquote id="b3">Blockquote
            <blockquote id="b4">Blockquote</blockquote>
        </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

CSS:

```
blockquote {
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
#b1 {
    background-color:#666;
}
#b2 {
    background-color:#f00;
}
#b3 {
    background-color:#0f0;
}
#b4 {
    background-color:#00f;
}
```

Comment: I added a new note...if I have ids on the blockquotes, that must be added through Jquery.