# styling nested blockquotes with alternative colours using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi there! I am attempting to use jQuery to add a border-left with different colours to a series of (theoretically infinite) nested blockquotes. This is so that it is easier to follow information contained in the blockquotes.

Like so:

```
<blockquote> 
    <blockquote>
        <blockquote>
             <blockquote>
                 content
             </blockquote>
             content
        </blockquote>
        content
    </blockquote>
    content
</blockquote>
```

Limitation: I can't manually add via html ids/classes to the blockquotes, as they are called up from Tumblr.

I've found [another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431452/differently-styling-nested-blockquotes) in which you add classes to the blockquotes via jQuery, and add the styling via CSS, however, I want to add CSS via jQuery and add the colours by going through a jQuery array of colours.

I've made an attempt here: [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bitternakano/c9bEy/4/).

```
//the array of colors
var colors = ["e45c5c","ffcc66","d7e972","76e2c2","5dc6cd",
          "be7ce4","e45c5c","ffcc66","d7e972"];

//in element article
    //find blockquote
      //for each blockquote
        //add the css border-left-color: # (colour can be found by going through 
        //through list of color codes)

 $('article').find('blockquote').each(function(){
     $(blockquote).css("border-left-color", "#" + colors[count]);
 });
```

I haven't really looked at js/jQuery much before this, so please excuse me if any of my use of terminology is confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parameter passed to the `each()` handler is the index of the current element. You can use this to get the required colour from your array with the modulo operator:

```
$('article').find('blockquote').each(function(i){
   $(this).css("border-left-color", "#" + colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9bEy/7/)

Also note the use of `this` inside the iteration to change the CSS of the current element only.

Answer (score 0):

There's one ugly work-around you might use, if you want it simple (and don't mind if it's not pretty).

Just style them all via css:

```
blockquote
{ border-left-color: #aaaaaa; }

blockquote blockquote
{ border-left-color: #bbbbbb; }

blockquote blockquote blockquote
{ border-left-color: #cccccc; }

blockquote blockquote blockquote blockquote
{ border-left-color: #dddddd; }

blockquote blockquote blockquote blockquote blockquote
{ border-left-color: #eeeeee; }

// ad infinitum (to some reasonable number)
```